# jquery click function only work its half

Tags: jquery, html

[my image of what is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBAD8.png)
I'm making notice board preview.
My `jQuery` code is below, and my click function just works on half of the div (horizontal). How can I fix this problem?
I've add some images and more codes.
its just not the problem of ids and classes, because both of it just works half.

```js
 $("#notice1").click(function(){
      popupNotice(n1);
  });
  $("#notice2").click(function(){
      popupNotice(n2);
  });
  $("#notice3").click(function(){
      popupNotice(n3);
  });
  $("#notice4").click(function(){
      popupNotice(n4);
  });
  $(".button").click(function(){
      win = new dhtmlXWindows().createWindow();
  });
```

```html
    #notice_view{
    height:185px;
    width:385px;
    border:2px solid grey;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-left: 870px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:white;
}
.notices{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-color:black;
    width:240px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
    z-index:50;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.dates{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-color:black;
    width:95px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
    z-index:50;
}
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <div class='container'>
            <div id="notice_view">
                <div class="b">더보기</div>
                <div id="notice1" class="notices"></div>
                <div id="date1" class="dates"></div>
                <div id="notice2" class="notices"></div>
                <div id="date2" class="dates"></div>
                <div id="notice3" class="notices"></div>
                <div id="date3" class="dates"></div>
                <div id="notice4" class="notices"></div>
                <div id="date4" class="dates"></div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$("#notice_view").click(function(){
      popupNotice(n1);
  });` can solve

Comment: can you attach some images before and after

Comment: upper code didn't solve my problem. :( I'll try to attach some images.

Comment: Can you add more code and Images, If there is an issue about how your div looks, then its not you JS, its probably CSS override, and vice-versa for JS

Comment: I've attached some images. I think something is covering my click area.

Comment: I think I found problem. input form of below my div was covering my area. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the images and your `CSS`, there's almost certainly a hidden element covering part of the notice and date fields. If you can identify that element and set a lower `z-index` to it, or set its `pointer-events: none`, you will be able to click through it and your `jQuery` should work for the entire `.notice-view` element.

Hope this helps!

```js
$("#notice1").click(function() {
  popupNotice(n1);
});
$("#notice2").click(function() {
  popupNotice(n2);
});
$("#notice3").click(function() {
  popupNotice(n3);
});
$("#notice4").click(function() {
  popupNotice(n4);
});
$(".button").click(function() {
  win = new dhtmlXWindows().createWindow();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

#notice_view {
  height: 185px;
  width: 385px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.notices {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.dates {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: black;
  width: 95px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class='container'>
      <div id="notice_view">
        <div class="b">더보기</div>
        <div id="notice1" class="notices">notice1</div>
        <div id="date1" class="dates">date1</div>
        <div id="notice2" class="notices">notice2</div>
        <div id="date2" class="dates">date2</div>
        <div id="notice3" class="notices">notice3</div>
        <div id="date3" class="dates">date3</div>
        <div id="notice4" class="notices">notice4</div>
        <div id="date4" class="dates">date4</div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you! sorry for late, but I learned a lot from you! thank you so much :)